# latex escape chars

Tags: latex, escaping, tex

I want to prepare a text for the use in a LaTeX document.

I wrote a SQL Function which does a lot of `REPLACE`. For example `_` -> `\_` and so on.

But there are so many special chars and sometimes I get errors. Does anyone know a SQL-function or a Java package for escaping text to LaTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only 10 special chars: `\ { } _ ^ # & $ % ~`.

Comment: Hey, Alexey, could you please edit your answer to add the tilde to the list? It will make the answer better for future readers.

Comment: I've added it. However, there are many other special characters, and the set isn't fixed: every character with a category code other than 11 or 12 will get special treatment.

Comment: Also don't forget to escape „-“ because two of them „--“ will be converted to „–“. Wrap it: „{-}{-}“

Answer (score 3):

Use a `verbatim` environment or the `listings` package, then you can enter source code without escaping.

Comment: That is similar to `<pre>` from HTML, meaning it has a strict, pre-defined formatting. Sometimes we just want to generate LaTeX code, and add text coming from SQL as normal paragraphs. Thus, such packages aren't adequate.

Comment: The `listings` package is pretty customizable. If you don't need syntax highlighting, simply redefine `\verbatim@font`.

Comment: That's not the point. If I want an entire paragraph, or just one value inside a table, I don't think we should use this verbatim package. For instance, this package won't automatically break lines and justify the text at the left and the right.